# how to make a color gradient for a container background in codename one

Tags: codenameone

tried to use CSS but failed is there a way to make a container background look like below
[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

Both the linear-gradient and radial-gradient CSS functions are fully supported by the Codename One CSS library (accorindg to the Codename One Developer Guide). But the background you want is not linear neither radial, as far as I know. So I don't think you can generate a similar image using a background gradient.

See:

- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_radial-gradient.asp

You can use `cn1-background-type`, `background-image` and `cn1-source-dpi` to have an image as background.

See: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/css.html

Comment: Hi Francesco Galgani, thats for your help i have got a solution from your answer, i wanted to ask you about something else , have you been able to change the color of the status bar in your apps if so guide me to about it. thanks and reguards;

Comment: Hi Tumwesigye Benjamin, next time try to post a new question when you ask something different, to get a better support from the Stack Overflow community. Said that, the StatusBar UIID is a special case that is only there on iOS. To change the color the iOS StatusBar, in a new Codename One bare bones project with iPhone X skin, try this CSS: `Toolbar {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;} StatusBar {padding: 4mm; background-color: red;}`